# WARNING: ConnectionID:1 Prelogin error: host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 Unexpected response type:74

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, javadb

Right now I am trying to make a simple DBConnection using Java. I am using the Eclipse IDE for the development.

```
import java.sql.*;


public class DbConnect {
    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:3306;databaseName=personal_AkiraDatabase";
    private static String user = "XXXX";
    private static String password = "XXXX";

    public static void main(String [] Args){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            if(con != null){
                System.out.println("Connection was a success!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Connection failed. :(");
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException :(");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("SQLException :(");
            }
        }

}
```

But currently it gives me this Error Message.

> Jul 05, 2014 7:20:15 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
>   WARNING: ConnectionID:1 Prelogin error: host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 Unexpected response type:74

I'm not even sure if it is a program problem, cause it was not an exception. The message just pops up in the console over and over again like as if it was in a loop.

I have tried:

- Googling up to 3 pages, other people's problems were a lot different than mine.
- Turning off all my Firewalls.
- netstat -an on CMD. **127.0.0.1:3306 is established.**
- Crying like a wee baby

### Currently:

- I have the DB on my local drive and I have a DB Named above. I
  actually have 1 test table on it.
- It does that error message with my Root password, with a admin user password and a random credential that is not in the user list of the database.
- I run my DB with MySQL Workbench

Possibly:

- I need to host my DB on something like XAMPP locally? Cause having it
  on MySqlServer is not enough?
- I just need to cry myself to sleep?

Thanks, And I am mostly online to answer for any vague details.

Here is a list of my LocalHost via netstat

```
    TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:7303         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:11990        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:11991        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:11999        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:7303         127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:10000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:11990        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:11991        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:11999        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:12025        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12110        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12119        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12143        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12465        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12563        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12993        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12995        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:27275        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Comment: It would be great if you can post full stacktrace.

Comment: There is actually no Stacktrace, Just that Error Message over and over until I manually terminate the process

Comment: 1434 is the default port. Did you add a firewall exception for that port?

Comment: I actually deactivated my windows firewall to remove that possibility. Still same.

Comment: Please post output of following command: netstat -an

Comment: @user3792604 to which database you r trying to connect? Is it Mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: @Fortune MySQL Server 5.0 Or rather MySQL

Comment: @user3792604 follow this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql

Comment: @user3792604 try sql server default ports for once. It seems you are using sqlserver drivers to connect to mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Mysql` as DB and trying to connect to `SQLSERVER` DB in your code. That is wrong.

An example database connection between `Java` and `Mysql` looks likes below:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personal_AkiraDatabase";
String username = "xxxx";
String password = "xxxxx"
Connection connection = null;
try {
    System.out.println("Connecting database...");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    System.out.println("Database connected!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

From : [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Comment: Yep that is it. Thank you and Thanks to @Darshan Lila. Sorry for my stupidity. lol!

Comment: @user3792604 tnx. Enjoy coding. :)